# Custom criteria of summary items with contextual filters in Views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Drupal 7. Views 3.

I have two contextual filters: terms of a vocabulary and dates. The no-results behavior is to display a summary, so I get three different screens in my view.

In the first screen, I see a list of terms. In the second, after clicking a term I see a list of dates associated with nodes tagged with that term. Then, after I click on a date, I see a node gallery.

On the first list, I want to be able to sort my list of terms by term weight, but the only sort criteria options I'm given in the contextual filter configuration are alphabetical or by number of records.

How does one custom-sort summary items of a contextual filter in Views 3?